# How to set default header in axios with Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, axios

I want to set default header with axios in Typescript.
Here is my function:

```
function setJwt(jwt: string | null) {axios.defaults.headers!.common["x-auth-token"] = jwt;}
```

This shows the following issue:
[image]

How to solve that in Typescript?

Comment: could you define a return type ? - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

Comment: yes no returned value so it is void in function declaration

Comment: can you post the whole script? Btw are you sure jwt is string? As it's saying not of type 'number'.

Comment: It's axios issue we need to keep an eye on this issue
https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4193

Answer (score 6):

I've fixed this by extending `HeadersDefaults` interface from axios.

```
 import axios, { HeadersDefaults } from 'axios' 

 interface CommonHeaderProperties extends HeadersDefaults {
   Authorization: string;
 }

 axiosInstance.defaults.headers = {
   Authorization: `Bearer authToken`
 } as CommonHeaderProperties;
```

Comment: what is axiosInstance?

Comment: https://axios-http.com/docs/instance

Comment: I think it would be good to include the axios.create in the example

Answer (score 3):

I succeed to solve the problem.
Well, `headers` property has a `Record<string, string>` type.

So, we should change the second generic type like this:

[image]

We cast to `unknown` first because we can't reconvert directy the type `Record`

Answer (score 2):

In the past (with axios v0.27.2) I did it like this:

```js
import axios, { AxiosRequestHeaders } from 'axios';

interface CustomAxiosRequestHeaders extends AxiosRequestHeaders {
  'x-auth-token': string;
  'api-lang': string;
}

const instance = axios.create();

instance.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
    request.headers = {
      'x-auth-token': getCurentJWT(),
      'api-lang': getLang(),
    } as CustomAxiosRequestHeaders;

    // ...

    return request;
  });
```

Now (with axios v1.2.3) I'm doing it the following way:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create();

instance.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
    request.headers.set('x-auth-token', getCurentJWT());
    request.headers.set('api-lang', getLang());

    // ...

    return request;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below,

```
function setJwt(jwt: string | null) {

    if (axios.defaults?.headers && axios.defaults.headers.common) {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['x-auth-token'] = jwt;
    }

}
```

Comment: The same issue because here, common property doesn't know about x-auth-token property, as I mentioned in my response below, headers property has Record<string, string> type so we need to change the second key to make it a type that contains x-auth-token property

Answer (score 0):

How to resolve with the declare module.

I wanted to define the basic typescript in HeadersDefaults instead of axiosInstance, so I applied it to the root path as follows.

```js
interface Authorization {
  Authorization: string;
}
declare module 'axios' {
  export interface HeadersDefaults extends Authorization {}
}
```